# Matlab: loss of Latex font on saving eps file

Tags: matlab, plot, fonts, eps

In Matlab, I am using `LaTex` interpreter as default and `CMU Serif` as in Latex as my default font through the following commands inside `startup.m`.

```
set(0,'DefaultTextFontname', 'CMU Serif');
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontName', 'CMU Serif');
set(0,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex');
```

The plot produced from `Matlab` appears like this, with the fonts in place:

[image]

However, upon saving the above image as `eps` using either `print` or `saveas` command produces figure with all the ticks and label in a different font:
[image]

Can someone suggest, what is the issue resulting in different fonts?

Comment: The [question I asked back in 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846941/is-it-possible-to-get-around-matlabs-limitation-on-font-embedding-in-vector-for) is still somehow relevant in 2016...

Comment: Any workaround for this? I already tried `Matlab2tikz` for couple of different plots and it works well. However, I had to abandon it as there continuously were minor issues arising during formatting.

Comment: Also tried `psfrag` in combination with `matlabfrag` and could not succeed as I use `pdflatex` instead of `LaTex`. I also tried the top answer in this link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11839/using-psfrag-with-pdflatex

Comment: It has been a few years since I was in a job where I was using LaTeX, so I don't know of a good workaround. I think that eventually I switched to outputting pdfs, which did a much better job of preserving fonts. If I needed the eps version, I would open it in Adobe Illustrator (my organization had a site license) and then save back out as eps. In my 2013 question, someone eventually posted an answer of how to do that very thing using ghostscript. YMMV.